# Build system of Sublime Text 3 executes a different version of PHP

Tags: php, macos, sublimetext3

I am using SublimeText3 on OSX. The problem is:

- If I execute PHP script on SublimeText3, then it is executed by PHP 5.5.
- But if I execute the same script from shell (iTerm), then it is executed by PHP 7.

How can I execute a script with PHP7 on SublimeText3?

The build system is following.

```
{
    "cmd" : ["php", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "php$",
    "selector"  : "source.php"
}
```

And the PHP script is just:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: Under OSX the path as seen by GUI applications like Sublime and the path that the terminal sees are not necessarily the same, so the terminal may be finding a different php executable. You can specify a path in the build system or put an explicit path on the php that your build system is executing to ensure it picks the right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the absolute path to the command (cmd).

Let's say `$file` is `/path/to/file`, then the command `['php', "$file"]` expands to `php /path/to/file`. This is like running the following on the command line:

```
$ php /path/to/file
```

Because the command (`php` ) is relative, the system path (on linux the system path is in the environment variable `PATH`) is searched to find `php`.

You can specify an absolute path for the command. Let's say you have the following versions installed:

- /path/to/php/versions/7.0.0/bin/php
- /path/to/php/versions/5.5.0/bin/php

Then you can configure a command to use v7.0.0:

```
{
    "cmd" : ["/path/to/php/versions/7.0.0/bin/php", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "php$",
    "selector"  : "source.php"
}
```

And v5.5.0:

```
{
    "cmd" : ["/path/to/php/versions/5.5.0/bin/php", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "php$",
    "selector"  : "source.php"
}
```

And so on...

### Further reading

- [What are Enviornment Variables](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)