# Possible to switch between python 2 and 3 in Sublime Text 3 build systems? (Windows)

Tags: python, sublimetext3

All my current coding has been in python 3, which I've installed via the Anaconda package. However I need to work on some code simultaneously in python 2. Is there a way I can add a build system in Sublime so I can switch between the two fluidly? I have both python 2 and 3 installed, however can't see a way of simply editing the build system slightly to switch between the two languages. The build system I'm using for python 3 is:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": true
}
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: change environment variable PATH to point to python 2 as well, but  change executable name to something like `python2.exe`. Now you can call python from cmd with pyhon2

Comment: I thought about this but there is no python entry in PATH (which I don't understand), only two Anaconda entries.

Comment: launch `where python` in command line, this will tell which python you're using when calling `python` from cmd. That probably gonna be one of your Anacondas. Then you can rename second one to what you want to call python 2 with.

Comment: Ok I have added a PATH to python 2, renamed the executable and edited the build command. When I put python2 --version into cmd it finds everything fine, but when I run the new build I'm getting:

'python2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Try rebooting your OS

Comment: Thanks very much, working now.

Answer (score 4):

Specify the absolute path to the version of Python. For example, if Python version 3 is located at `/usr/bin/python3` and Python version 2 is located at `/usr/bin/python2`:

Python 3 Build Configuration:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": true
}
```

Python 2 Build Configuration:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/bin/python2", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": true
}
```

Find the location of Python via `which`:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

$ which python2
/usr/bin/python2
```

See [Build system of Sublime Text 3 executes a different version of PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40004464/934739), it is the same principal.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but...

On Windows, you dont need create a new build system or specify the absolute path. Edit already existing python build system.

1. In `SublimeText\Data\Packages\` create folder `Python` -> like this `SublimeText\Data\Packages\Python\`
2. In this folder, create file `Python.sublime-build` , it will overwrite the existing python build system.
3. In this file write ([python launcher documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows)):

   ```
   {
       "shell_cmd": "py -u \"$file\"",
       "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
       "selector": "source.python",
       "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},
   }
   ```
4. For choose version of python interpretator, in the first line of your scripts write ([shebang lines](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines))

   - `#! python` or
   - `#! python3`

Answer (score 0):

1, intall pyhton3:
https://www.python.org/downloads/

2, find the file "python.exe" and rename to "python3.exe"

3, in Windows command line:

```
where python3.exe
```

Save this ubication wherever you want.

4, In sublime goto -> Tools -> Build system -> New build system (this open a file)

5, finally the ubication file of number 3, only change the ubication:

```
{
    /*replace this*/"cmd": ["C:/Users/youruser/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python3.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": true
}
```

Save the file like "python3".

6, In sublime go to Tools -> Build system -> Select python3 and you can run this code in python 3.

7, Show your python version:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

If you want to run in python 2, then go to Tools -> Build system -> Select "Python"