# keyword argument of print function in python

Tags: python

This might be a silly question, but I really don't know which part is wrong?

I wrote the following code:

```
b = 0
while b < 10:
    print(b, end=" ")
    b = b + 1
```

But I always got this error message:

```
  File "/Users/l/Desktop/test.py", line 3
    print(b, end=" ")
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could someone give me a little help? Thanks!

Comment: This code runs fine for me can you try restarting your python terminal and check  whether you have defined any of your variables or even `print` elsewhere

Comment: Runs fine for me too! Turn it off and on again...

Comment: What's your Python version?

Comment: It seems you are running Python 2.x, not Python 3.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, this is a Python3 feature, but you can emulate this behavior in Python2 as well, like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

print('Now it works', end='!')
```

See [this link](http://python-future.org/imports.html#future-imports) for more on future imports.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: If this helped you I would appreciate if you'd accept this as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This syntax is valid only in Python3, you're probably using Python2.

Python3:

```
print("Hello World", end="!") # OUTPUT: Hello World!
```

Python2:

```
print("Hello World", end="!")
```

> File "...\python test.py", line 5
>       print("Hello World", end="!")
>     SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Are you using sublime text? if so, you can have both python working, you just choose which one will compile

Comment: Yes, I am using sublime text. It's just... I am still not very familiar with it.

Comment: check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024713/possible-to-switch-between-python-2-and-3-in-sublime-text-3-build-systems-wind/40031389#40031389) or open a different one for enable both python versions in sublime text

Answer (score 1):

Python 2 and 3

```
from __future__ import print_function

b = 0
while b < 10:
    print(b, end=" ")
    b = b + 1
```

Comment: I just tried. This works. And I now know the problem is due to my python version. I might need to change some settings of my text editor. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In python 3 your code will  work fine, but in python 2 do this :

```
b = 0
while b < 10:
  print b ,  #put comma at end 
  b = b + 1

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Thanks. I know that the issue is due to my python version now. This solution works.

Comment: happy coding !!